# Why is max function giving on error on list of numbers?

Tags: list, dataframe, pyspark

I have a list obtained from a df from a previous function, but it's structured like a normal list:

```
list1 = [45, 789, 52, 7962, 54, 5, 78]
```

when I try to call max(list1), i get an error that says: Invalid argument, not a string or column.
I've tried just defining a new list to see if the error came from the gettign of it from a function:

```
test = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

But max(test) resulted in the same error. Why is this happening?

Comment: are you importing the functions as `from pyspark.sql.functions import *` ?

Comment: @AnandVidvat yes

Comment: in that case, the python interpreter is treating the max function as pyspark function instead python native `max` function. you can avoid this by using `from pyspark.sql  import functions as F` so that you can be more specific like `F.max()` ,`F.round()` when calling your sql functions vs when calling python native functions.

Comment: @AnandVidvat it's still giving this error even after the change: Invalid argument, not a string or column: [45, 789, 52, 7962, 54, 5, 78] of type <class 'list'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.

Comment: could you paste your script from imports and where you are actually calling the function?

Comment: You will need to restart kernel if using Jupyter, or start another Python session if using command line, `from pyspark.sql  import functions as F` will solve your problem